# how to compare values of two columns using php in the same table and color them if same value

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

```
if(column1 == column2)
{
 if(grade !=5 || grade != 'INC' || grade !='DRP' || grade !='TRF' )
 {
  color column green
 }
 else
 {
  color column red
 }
}
```

Comment: Use `in_array()` instead.

Comment: Could you explain your problem a little bit more?

Comment: well the code above is running and theres no problem in it .. and the main problem is i have a two columns  subject code and prerequisite and they are in the same table i want to compare the value of prerequisite into subject code column .. how to do that? i can compare the row but the culomn is a bit hard for me.. sorry im a newbie in php

Comment: Why can't you compare columns with `$row['column1'] == $row['column2']`?

Comment: Or do the comparison in SQL: `SELECT IF(column1=column2, 'red', 'green')) AS color`

Comment: i can compare them if they are in the same row.. but they are not.

Comment: ok ill try it sir barmar ill use that SQL comparison

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running this code.  Make changes do it as you see fit.

```
$column1 = array("one", "two", "three", "two", "five", "eight");
$column2 = array("seven", "four", "six", "three", "one", "five", "eleven");

foreach($column1 as $key=>$value){

    foreach($column2 as $key2=>$value2){

            echo "Value1: $value  Value2: $value2";

            if($value == $value2){
                echo " -- <font style='color:#00f200;'>Values are the same</font><br/>";
            }else{
                echo " -- <font style='color:red;'>Values are not the same</font><br/>";
            }
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the logic wrong, you should be using `&&`, not `||`:

```
if ($grade !=5 && $grade != 'INC' && $grade !='DRP' && $grade !='TRF' )
```

The way you wrote it, it will always be true, so everything will be green.

You're also missing `$` prefixes on your variables.

Comment: thanks barmar.. but my problem is comparing values in two coulums in the same table

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array(5, 'INC', 'DRP', 'TRF');

if(in_array(strtolower($grade), strtolower($array)))
 {
  color column green
 }
 else
 {
  color column red
 }
```

For added cleanliness and reliability. :)